# RDWeb: How to block clipboard and printer redirection for 'Connect to a Remote PC' only

Tags: remote-access, iis, windows-server-2016

I've got a 2016 RDWeb Gateway.  I want to allow users to have clipboard and printer redirection for the 'RemoteApp and Desktop' links, but I don't want to allow it for 'Connect to a Remote PC'.

I see the IIS Application settings to block it via the xClipboard and xPrinterRedirection settings, but I fear this will apply to all connections and not just for the 'Connect to a Remote PC' connections.

I don't see a way in Gateway Manager or NPS to limit those specific settings via security group, which would be an ok alternative.

Anyone know how to block one but not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xClipboard and xPrinterRedirection settings in IIS will be applied to "RemoteApp and Desktop", but will not be applied "Connect to a remote PC".

As the computer the user would like to connect via "Connect to a remote PC" is not fixed, there is no such setting to block clipboard and printer redirection for all remote connections.

The user will need to uncheck **Printers** and **Clipboard** in the option list when connecting to a remote PC.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khe9y.png)

Another way is to set group policy on the remote PC to block clipboard and printer redirection. But the redirection will be blocked for all connecions to that PC. If you set the policy on your remote app session host server, the redirection will also be blocked for the remote app.

**Computer Configuration\Administratives Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection - Do not allow Clipboard redirection**

**Computer Configuration\Administratives Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Printer Redirection - Do not allow client printer redirection**

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for confirming those details for me!